# deliver_later not working good in rails tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task, actionmailer, rails-activejob

I'm using tasks to complete background jobs. For example my remove_badges.rake file in lib/tasks :

```
desc "Remove expired badges rake task"
task :remove_expired_badges => :environment do

  message = "remove_expired_badges is running now."
  HostMailer.send_system_info_mail(message).deliver_later

  BadgeHost.all.each do |b|
    if b.expire_at < Time.now
      begin
        b.destroy
        puts "An expired badge successfully deleted."

        host = b.host
        badge = b.badge
        HostMailer.send_badge_removed_email(host, badge).deliver_later

      rescue
        puts "Failed to destroy expired badge."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

First mail is to myself for being sure this task is running.
Second mail is to user to inform he lost his badge.

I've other tasks also, in one of them mails are working fine.

But in other tasks, mails are not sent. Only if I delete deliver_later and use deliver, mails are sent.

I dont want to use deliver, because it is making a pause until the mail sent.

Is there is a reason you know causing deliver_later not working good with rails tasks?

Comment: No idea, same happened to me using deliver_now as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 4):

I was just working on a rake task in a Rails 5.0.1 application that sends out emails. I was using the default setup of the :async adapter for ActiveJob (development mode). I was also using the letter_opener gem in development so that emails would pop up in my browser rather than be sent.

Everything looked good when I ran the task with each email using .deliver_now.

In order to let the task finish quickly, I switched the rake task so that each email it generates is enqueued with .deliver_later rather than .deliver_now.

I could see the emails getting enqueued by ActiveJob:

[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob ...

but no emails were popping up in letter opener.

It turns out that the problem was that I didn't understand how :async works. Basically, what's going on is that :async is an in memory queue that only lasts as long as the process that creates it lives. With a rake task, the emails get enqueued correctly (in memory), but then the task ends and the memory queue gets cleared out. But that happens before any processing time has been given to the ActiveJob thread.

To test that things are working in development, any of the following will work:

```
Use .deliver_now
Add a sleep(5) to the end of your rake task (just for manual testing ... delete that before you commit)
Switch to a different ActiveJob adapter that stores the jobs in some durable queue / db and runs as a separate process from your rake task
```

ANSWER TAKEN FROM: http://stevechanin.blogspot.com/2017/05/deliverlater-not-working-in-rake-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to understand: When the rake/rails task finishes, some threads will get terminated that have to do with background tasks such as deliver_later. That was a statement in one of the guides at rubyonrails.org, so it's official and documented that deliver_later doesn't work in rails tasks. I'd really like to supply the link here, I will edit when I have found it.